# How does python references work in a list

Tags: python, arrays, multiplication

I was reading this post [How to Initialize a 2d Array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/240178/list-of-lists-changes-reflected-across-sublists-unexpectedly/30759580#30759580)

I understand that the issue here is that a list is referencing the same list. So if you edit one of the elements. All the references will reflect this change.

But in a case such as:

```
x = 1
y  = [x]*5
# y = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
x = 2
# why doesn't y = [2, 2, 2, 2, 2]??
```

Shouldn't y change because each element is referencing x?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You misunderstood. There are 5 **distinct references**. If those 5 references all point to the same nested list and you alter that nested list, you can see the change reflected through all those references.

You didn't change a nested list here. You changed one of the references.

Think of references as nametags. You can put more than one nametag on an object:

```
nametag_a+-----------+
                 +---v--+
                 |object|
                 +---^--+
                     |
nametag_b+-----------+
```

You can 'look' at the object through either reference. Assignment is simply attaching a reference to an object. If a reference pointed to an object before, it is detached from that object and now points to another object:

```
nametab_b = another_object
```

results in

```
nametag_a+-----------+
                 +---v--+
                 |object|
                 +------+

nametag_b    +--------------+
    +-------->another_object|
             +--------------+
```

The numbered indices in a list are references to; so instead of `nametag_a`, you have `0`, and `1`, etc.

The other question talks about nested lists. There you have multiple references to a single list object:

```
# indices in a list on the left referencing another list

0+---------------------------+
                             |
                             |
1+------------------------+  |
                          |  |
                +---------v--v-----------+
2+--------------> list with more indices |
                +---------^--^-----------+
                          |  |
3+------------------------+  |
                             |
                             |
4+---------------------------+
```

If you make a change to the `list with more indices` contents, then you'll see those changes through any of the 5 references in the outer list

Please read [*Facts and myths about Python names and values*](https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html) by Ned Batchelder, which explains this in more detail.

Comment: does `[x]*5` create a new object that is list containing the value of `x`, and this is why that works like this?

Comment: @KGS: Yes, multiplying a list creates a new list object with all the references from the old list copied over. So you had a list with 1 reference, now you have a new list with 5 references. The object that `x` references is not copied, you just get more references.

Answer (score 0):

Great site to further understanding the situation.

[Python Tutor](http://pythontutor.com/live.html#mode=edit)

[image]